# Questions regarding audio for games in C++ (engine type stuff) and working with .ogg

Tags: c++, audio, audio-player

For the quick and concise: I want to find out how to work with .ogg files in visual c++ to put it in a format the PC can play and have tools to control how it's played and be able to play multiple at once, but all of it limited to a 2d scale. Preferably with no or very little cost. Also I've heard about streaming audio but I'm not so sure what the details on that are. The rest is an explanation of my though process on the whole thing, which is likely flawed in other areas this short hand doesn't convey but getting the short hand down will make that apparent eventually.

So I'm working on a game which will be wholly in the 2D space, for purposes of self improvement I want to try and build the engine myself and work things the best I can. For audio I'm thinking ahead of how to program it while I finish with the visual side of things, and have gotten an idea of things I want to be able to do with the sound but I'm inexperienced and probably have a flawed sense of the basic process. So I'll list what I functions I'll need done and my current mindset of how to approach it. After this I'll clarify my issues with .ogg. So the functions I know I'll need at current are:

- Ability to play audio files
- Ability to change volume of audio files mid playback
- Ability to play them starting a specific times (this along with the above to allow for me to fade a background song out and play a different version of the same background music at where the last one dropped off)
- Ability to play them in a loop
- Ability to play multiple audio files at the same time (sound effects with background music.)
- Ability to pan sounds to one ear or the other when using headphones and such.

Now for my mindset of how to approach it:

- When loading in decode the audio files and load them into objects I can reference later on that same screen, scene, or event till I no longer need them and can delete them.
- have events which will call audio effects which will play them or change things. IE: player gets hit, sound plays then ends.
- I think I'll need buffers or channels to play them like 1 channel for background music, another for a secondary background music that fades into the current as I fade out and remove the current. Then I can free up the first channel for another fading of tracks. Then a few more to make space for sound effects. Like say 10 that stay empty but allow for me to play a sound in one, then delete it and then go back and play some other effect in that same channel later. However if I need to play multiple sound effects at once I can play up to 10 at the same time. However if I need them I'm not sure if I'll be able to clear them up or each channel has its own song tied to it instead of me being able to pass the decoded sound to what it has set to play.
- Then every frame progresses the sound being played, I'm not exactly sure if I need or will do this. I intend to try and work online play into my game using rollback netcode. From my experience sounds don't freeze or progress based on connection and just run on. As in game freezes from connection waiting for opponent, the background music will play like normal. If it freezes on a hit, the hit sound should just play out once and end so desync there should be fine but I am kind of curious on how and if there is a good reason for it. I also heard a term dropped, streaming, I'm trying to understand how to go about it but I struggled to get a good grasp on it.

That's about it for how I think I should go about it, if I had to come up with a sort psuedo code probably would be:

```
LoadScene(..., file backgroundsounda, file backgroundsoundb, file soundeffecthit){
.
.
.
Backsadeco = new decodedsound(backgroundsounda)
.
.
.
LoadScene.setBackSoundA(backsadeco)
.
.
.
LoadScene.makeBuffers(2,10)
//makeBuffers from a Buffer class which makes two for the background and 10 effect buffers that the scene can reference later for those purposes. The buffers use a switch statement to denote how to play the sound based on number given later. EX:1 plays sound once and then empties buffer. Buffer also manages which effect or background buffer to use by checking which ones aren't playing sound. 

}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


class collision

strikeHit(...,scene){
.
.
.
scene.useEffectBuffer(scene.getSoundEffectHit(),1)

} 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

(the pseudo code above for handling the scene stuff could also be flawed cause I haven't gotten to making scene system yet with load screens and such, first I want to get what I need done and existing in one scene first then work on handling the transitions. Though if you have advice on that I'm all ears too.)

Aside from any potential flaws in my plan when I can play sound, working with ogg which I planned to use since its' a smaller file size and planning to have 3 versions of every song which can go upwards of 2 minutes each would be wise, I'm not sure how or what to do. I've heard of OpenAL but I'm confused on the license stuff and since I plan to hopefully sell the game one day and I want to reduce costs I'm trying to avoid fees where I can. Secondly I hear it has quite a few stuff for 3d and I'm not so sure since all my actions are intended for 2d and at most I'll pan sounds, if it's worth it or if I can manage something more streamlined and focused for my needs. Realistically all I should need is a way to format it to be played by the PC and then tools to handle how that is played. Also understanding of how to keep the PC playing it as the rest of the game updates and changes logically and visually on 60fps.

Edit based on first comment: I intend to keep it usable by multiple systems but limited to Windows, focusing on Windows 10 currently. I am working In visual studio and so far have just used things available there for my needs so I think the only framework would be .NET. As for video playing, at current I don't have a need for that since I plan to work more so with 2d images and animation, and currently can't find a purpose for it. As for licenses I'm not well versed on that topic but I'm trying to stay free for commercial use if possible.

Comment: Need to know if portability is an issue, which licences you accept (or don't / can't accept), if you use a framework above like Qt, Unreal, etc., and so on. Otherwise, I would advice you to search for a C++ library which encapsulates FFMPEG, since it will also solve the most probable next problem: playing videos...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).